# PN532 with Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: i2c, serial, pi-pico, nfc

I have PN532 NFC Module that looks like this
[image]

I am trying to connect this NFC Module with Pico, but I have no luck in finding library that allows me this. What can I do to control it? Can you recommend any library? It can be any connection, but I prefer I2C.

Thanks!

Comment: This PN532 SO Q&A might help a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165652/how-can-rpi-read-a-i2c-spi-pn532-nfcrfid-nfc-module/61220607#61220607

Comment: pico thonny ide spakage manager search results contains a couple of micro python libraries, but I not tried them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library:

Micropython PN532 NFC/RFID control library (SPI)
https://github.com/Carglglz/NFC_PN532_SPI

Use the following micropython example to read the cards:

```
import NFC_PN532 as nfc
from machine import Pin, SPI

# SPI
spi_dev = SPI(0, baudrate=400000, sck=Pin(18), mosi=Pin(19), miso=Pin(16))
cs = Pin(17, Pin.OUT)
cs.on()

# SENSOR INIT
pn532 = nfc.PN532(spi_dev,cs)
ic, ver, rev, support = pn532.get_firmware_version()
print('Found PN532 with firmware version: {0}.{1}'.format(ver, rev))

# Configure PN532 to communicate with MiFare cards
pn532.SAM_configuration()

# FUNCTION TO READ 
def read_nfc(dev, tmot):
    """Accepts a device and a timeout in millisecs """
    print('Reading...')
    uid = dev.read_passive_target(timeout=tmot)
    if uid is None:
        print('CARD NOT FOUND')
    else:
        numbers = [i for i in uid]
        string_ID = '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(*numbers)
        print('Found card with UID:', [hex(i) for i in uid])
        print('Number_id: {}'.format(string_ID))

while True:
    read_nfc(pn532, 500)
```